# Connection of a regular surface obtained through implicit function theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$. It is immediate to see that $1$ is a non-critical value for $F$. Then, it can be shown that $F^{-1}(1)$ is a regular surface. Indeed, I obtain the sphere, that is a connected set. In general, if $F$ is a polynomial in three variables and $c$ a non-critical value, we have that each connected component of $F^{-1}(c)$ is a regular surface. Which condition is needed to ensure that $F^{-1}(c)$ is connected?

Comment: What did you _actually_ want to way with "each connected component of $F^{-1}(c)$ is connected"? Because as it stands, it's kindof obvious.

Comment: In general, this is an extremely difficult problem and there are no simple criteria for guaranteeing connectedness. For example, note that if you change to $F(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z^2$, then $F^{-1}(c)$ is connected for $c\ge 0$ and disconnected for $c<0$. See, for example, [Hilbert's 16th Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixteenth_problem).